# Cannot get width of DIV in AngularJS modal window

Tags: javascript, dom

I put this code into the index.html file or the view (html) file in my AngularJS web app and it works like a charm:

```
<div id="chart"></div>

<script>
    var chart = document.getElementById("chart");
    alert("width is : " + chart.offsetWidth);
</script>
```

I can resize my browser window and when I refresh, it tells me the new width.

However, when I put this code in with the code for a modal window in the view (html) file, I get "width is : 0"

Does anybody know why and how I can get the width of a DIV in a modal window?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Angular. Also, we're going to probably need more information.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but in case you or someone else haven't figured it out yet:

You need to make sure you get the value you're looking for AFTER the element(s) have been rendered. Otherwise you will always get '0'

That is why in jQuery you wrap your code in a block like this:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

There are a few variants of this;
In pure JS you would use 'document.onLoad'

Answer (score -3):

If you're using jQuery you can use

```
$('#chart').width()
```

http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: Roy:  Thanks for replying.  I am using JQuery and I tried putting your code in both the HTML file that has the modal window HTML code as well as in the controller.js file and both of them returned 0.